# How revocation status of delegated OCSP responder is verified at the client side?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, ocsp

If the OCSP signing is delegated explicitly to another entity and that delegated OCSP responder is compromised, how to revoke the certificate and convey the revocation information to a client? We need CRL for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCSP signing certificates are not normally revoked.  Clients are made aware of this requirement using the non-critical `id-pkix-ocsp-nocheck` extension.  To reduce the effect of a compromise of these certificates they are normally issued with a short lifetime.

However, this isn't the only option.  OCSP signing certificates could be revocable and checks could be carried out using a CRL or any method described in [RFC 5280's Authority Information Access](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.2.1). Note that this only defines OCSP as an option, in which case it would need to be a different OCSP responder to be meaningful.

Details are in [RFC 6960 Section 4.2.2.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6960#section-4.2.2.2.1).